# Does anyone know the code for the symbol less than or greater than \lessgtr in latex

Tags: latex, symbols

Need to know the code for symbol less than or greater than in this format:

[image]

Note: detexify and the comprehensive book of symbols were with no help.

Also this one is depreciated:

```
\lessgrt\limits_{noise}^{speech}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[
y_k \mathop{\lessgtr}_{noise}^{speech} \eta
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]